# Apache can't find localhost/~user directory

Tags: php, macos, apache, terminal

Hi every one I'm setting up apache following a tutorial on OS X Yosemite.
I can get to the "It works" page from default WebServer directory but when setting up my own user directory apache doesn't find it anymore. I created the Sites directory in my User folder.
Then I created the username.conf in `/etc/apache2/users` I also have a Guest.conf there that's not mentioned in my tutorial but I don't know if it is the problem and I'd rather ask than delete it without knowing.

my username.conf file :

```
<Directory "/Users/mathiashintjens/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I used `sudo chmod 644 mathiashintjens.conf` to changes privileges then `sudo apachectl restart`

Then I created an index.html file in my ~/Sites directory and yet I still can't open it in my browser using `http://localhost/~mathiashintjens/`

I have installed MAMP in the past so maybe here lies the problem?

If anyone could help me it would be really cool.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you enabled user dirs? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/public_html.html

Comment: I could find the same line as in your link in "httpd.conf" I did find "Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf" and uncommented it but safari couldn't even find localhost anymore, so I tried to uncomment the userdir_module too, but now I get the same 404 not found as when both where inactive

Comment: I mean I couldn't find*